Vocalization of תצפה in נשמת כל-חי
In various siddurim I have seen the word תצפה—near the end of the Nishmat prayer of Shabbat and Yom Tov—vocalized as either תְצַפּה or תִצְפּה. Which is correct in this context?
(Thanks to Joel K for the distinction between them.)

can you please either quote the phrase in question or link to it? I'm feeling rather dense -- I don't know what you are referring to.

@rosends וכל עין לך תצפה

Re your side question. One is kal, the other piel. So not really synonymous. https://www.pealim.com/search/?q=%D7%9C%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA

The 'Avodas Hashem" siddur used by Belz Chasidim has both, one of them in square brackets - i don't remember which-  and I think that means that they say both.

If you accept that the Alter Rebbe was extremely precise in the nusach he recorded in his Siddur (the tradition is that he went through 60 different manuscripts to determine the precise and correct text), then it’s worth noting that he uses the form: תְצַפּה.

@JoelK Thank you!

מֹ֮שֵׁ֤ל בִּגְבוּרָת֨וֹ׀ עוֹלָ֗ם עֵ֭ינָיו בַּגּוֹיִ֣ם תִּצְפֶּ֑ינָה

https://tora-forum.co.il/threads/%d7%95%d7%9b%d7%9c-%d7%a2%d7%99%d7%9f-%d7%9c%d7%9a-%d7%aa%d7%a6%d7%a4%d7%94.26656/  נוסח ספרד: וְכָל עַיִן לְךָ תְּצַפֶּה נוסח עדות המזרח: וְכָל עַיִן לְךָ תְּצַפֶּה

The שערי תשובה on או"ח רפא אות א writes that anyone who says תְצַפּה is mistaken, and one must say תִצְפּה. However, the אבודרהם brings 2 פסוקים, each one supporting each version.
